# Redirect and keep my favicon 

Tags: facebook, browser, iframe, redirect, favicon

I was wondering how facebook redirects keeps its favicon when you click a link on facebook its open new tab with the FB favicon

I am wondering how could this be accomplished

Its not iframe so how could i do such thing

Where I should start ?
And while the redirect there is a URL called maybe it does everything

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Google Chrome. I'm pretty sure you are referring to a known bug.
See [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80635) which was merged into [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=79667).

> **What steps will reproduce the problem?**
>
> 1. Visit site with /favicon.ico (e.g. facebook.com)
> 2. Receive a redirect from this domain to a new domain without a /favicon.ico
> 3. The favicon for the new url is inherited from the last domain.
>
> **What is the expected result?**
>
> Favicon is blank.
>
> **What happens instead?**
>
> Favicon is inherited from last domain.
>
> **Other information:**
>
> I discovered this as facebook.com does not link directly to external
>   sites, but logs the url then redirects to it. I reproduced the issue
>   on localhost using the 'redirect' statement in the ruby web-framework
>   'Sinatra'.

Answer (score -1):

Your browser stores the favicon and groups it with domain name of the site your visiting.
In other words, once you've loaded facebook once, it will show up on all facebook pages.

Comment: I know that 
but the question how can I make your website for example have my favicon, as happens with FB